# Сохранить звуковой файл на сервере

Tags: php, javascript, frontend, аудио

Работаю с p5.sound.js. Необходимо сохранить .wav файл на сервер, или просто вывести записанный аудио-сигнал через тег audio.
Вместо этого файл просто скачивается через браузер.

```
var mic, recorder, soundFile;
var state = 0; // mousePress will increment from Record, to Stop, to Play
var mic, recorder, soundFile;
var state = 0; // mousePress will increment from Record, to Stop, to Play

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400);
  background(200);
  fill(0);
  text('Enable mic and click the mouse to begin recording', 20, 20);
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
  recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();
  recorder.setInput(mic);
  soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (state === 0 && mic.enabled) {
    recorder.record(soundFile);
    background(255,0,0);
    text('Recording now! Click to stop.', 20, 20);
    state++;
  }
  else if (state === 1) {
    recorder.stop(); // stop recorder, and send the result to soundFile
    background(0,255,0);
    text('Recording stopped. Click to play & save', 20, 20);
    state++;
  }
  else if (state === 2) {
    soundFile.play(); // play the result!
    saveSound(soundFile, 'mySound.wav'); // save file
    state++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно переопределить `p5.prototype.writeFile`, Создать `Blob` и преобразовать в `base64`
Выводим в тег `audio`

```js
var mic, recorder, soundFile, state = 0, audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');

p5.prototype.writeFile = function(blob, name, type){
 blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
  blob.name = name;
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob(blob, {type: "audio/"+type}));
 reader.onloadend = function() {
  audio[0].src = reader.result;
 }
}

function setup() {
 createCanvas(400,40);
 background(200);
 fill(0);
 text('Enable mic and click the mouse to begin recording', 20, 20);
 mic = new p5.AudioIn();mic.start();
 recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();
 recorder.setInput(mic);
 soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();
}

function mousePressed() {
 if (state === 0 && mic.enabled) {
  recorder.record(soundFile);
  background(255,0,0);
  text('Recording now! Click to stop.', 20, 20);
  state++;
 } else if (state === 1) {
  recorder.stop();
  background(0,255,0);
  text('Recording stopped. Click to play', 20, 20);
  state++;
 } else if (state === 2) {
  saveSound(soundFile, 'mySound.wav');
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/processing/p5.js-sound/master/lib/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/processing/p5.js-sound/master/lib/p5.sound.js"></script>
<audio controls></audio>
```

Вполне возможно, что код не будет работать на страницах stackoverflow и локально, но [с сервера работает](https://studionions.ru/sound.php).